# ToList() - ArgumentNullException Handling

Tags: c#, argumentnullexception

Hi I have a class named Activity,

On a form I create its object array as,

```
 Activity[] _actList;
```

And then do this,

```
List<Activity> termsList = _actList.ToList<Activity>();
```

since `_actiList` is null its throwing the `ArgumentNullException`.

So my question is,

How can I handle this exception?
Or is there a work around to get the same functionality ?

Please Help!

Comment: do you mean without initializing? are you expecting an empty list?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Yes without initializing

Comment: without initializing `_actList` what are you expecting the machine to put in `termsList`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to check for null before calling `ToList`

```
var termsList = _actList == null ? null : _actList.ToList();
```

If you are using the C# 6.0 or later you can write the same in a shorter way:

```
var termsList = _actList?.ToList();
```

You could also catch the exception, but I don't recommend that in this case especially if it is a common scenario for the array to be `null`

Comment: @Sunitha Glad to help :). FYI no need to specify type parameter for `ToList`, you can, but the compiler can figure it out so it's recommended to leave it out unless you have a good reason to put it there.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure that the array is never null with assigning an empty default array.

```
Activity[] _actList = new Activity[] { };
```

so, when the form is initialized the array also will be initialized with an empty array. If you are doing .ToList() now, you will get an empty list then instead of an exception.

Comment: instance of abstract class ?

Comment: @bansi It is not an instance of the `Activity` class. It is an instance of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Using try catch which would work for any such issue:

```
try {
    List<Activity> termsList = _actList.ToList<Activity>();
}
catch(ArgumentNullException){

}
```

Or you can use set a default value if it is null using the ?? operator:

```
List<Activity> termsList = (_actList ?? new Employee[] { }).ToList<Activity>();
```

This would give you an empty list if your array is empty.